# CSS Bootstrap Responsive Menu Discrepancy

Tags: php, wordpress, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation

I am developing a site for a local legal firm and have run across an odd CSS problem.
The collapsed responsive menu is displayed two different ways. Using Screenfly from Quirktools I noticed two devices have menu CSS problems.

The first and correct way is found here 
THIS HAS BEEN FIXED
That link is for devices with a screen resolution of  603px x 966px.

The second and incorrect way is found here
THIS HAS BEEN FIXED
THIS HAS BEEN FIXED
The first link targets devices with a screen resolution of 800px x 1280px
The second targets devices with a screen resolution of 768px x 1024px

The next size up a 10" netbook is also fine and can be found here
THIS HAS BEEN FIXED
This one targets devices with a screen resolution of 1024px x 600px

The site in question is 
THIS HAS BEEN FIXED

Does anyone know what would cause this or how to fix it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I haven't worked with Bootstrap before and it can be a bit confusing.

Best,
Tim

Comment: post your code, friend!

Comment: Also, please specify what about the first links is "correct" and what about the 2nd and 3rd is not.

Comment: @ShawnTaylor he corrected the two issues..That is why you dont see the difference anymore in the links.

Comment: Thank you Sam Ram Sudheer. That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `float:right` on `.header-contact` you layout breaks at 650px

So add this media query

```
@media (max-width: 650px) {
  .header-contact{
  float:left;
  }
}
```

The next nav-bar design breaks because you are toggling your `nav-bar at 818px` and the color applied to the nav-bar is by this query.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {

.menu-nav ul {border:none;}
.navbar-collapse{background:#353f00;}

}
```

So anything screen above `767px` there will be a problem till `818px`.

Change the query to `818px`

```
 @media (max-width: 818px) {  
    .menu-nav ul {border:none;}
    .navbar-collapse{background:#353f00;}

    }
```